# jQuery Change Input text upon selection of radio button having multiple forms in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im looking to do something like @JCOC611 did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5099898/3223200

In which you can change the TEXT value depending on the RADIO BUTTON selection

Who ever, I would like to have several forms in the same page, how can this be done?

The original code is

```
<input type="text" id="it" value="">
<input type="radio" name="hey" value="one">
<input type="radio" name="hey" value="two">
<input type="radio" name="hey" value="three">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
     $("#it").val(this.value);
  }); 
});
</script>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/rhcd2/1/

And I would like something like this:

```
<form action="hello.php" name="form01" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="productid" value="01" />
<input type="radio" name="price" value="1000">
<input type="radio" name="price" value="2000">
<input type="text" id="it" name="pricevalue" value="">
</form>

<form action="hello.php" name="form02" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="productid" value="02" />
<input type="radio" name="price" value="6000">
<input type="radio" name="price" value="2400">
<input type="text" id="it" name="pricevalue" value="">
</form>

<form action="hello.php" name="form03" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="productid" value="03" />
<input type="radio" name="price" value="500">
<input type="radio" name="price" value="700">
<input type="text" id="it" name="pricevalue" value="">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
     $("#it").val(this.value);
  }); 
});
</script>
```

Using multiple forms in the same page, but to use the same function

How can this be done?

Comment: You should not have multiple elements in the DOM with same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text]").val(this.value);
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JKM4D/)**

By using `.closest()` and `.find()` you can pick the text input element closest to the relative radio button selected.

Note that IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 0):

A bit less code if you use `siblings()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
       $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val(this.value);
    }); 
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tleish/rhcd2/129/)