# HTML,PHP. Change text in textarea cause of checked(change) radio button

Tags: javascript, php, html, radio-button, textarea

Hello I want change text in textarea on click(change) radio button. I have own database clanok(article) where attributes are nadpis(title) and text. Thanks.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM clanok ORDER BY nadpis");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="nadpis" value="<?php echo $row['nadpis']; ?> "> 
<?php
echo $row['nadpis'];
echo "<br>";  
}
?>
<textarea name="text" cols="30" rows="5" >                       
<?php
echo $row['text'];
?>
</textarea> 
<br>                
<input type="submit"  value="Odoslať článok">
```

Comment: Solution for your answer involves jquery. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099841/jquery-change-input-text-upon-selection-of-radio-button)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, after the page is finished loading, you cannot fetch new stuff from the database and show it on your page (unless you use ajax), so this means that ALL of your rows of text should be loaded and stored somewhere beforehand.

Or, you can use ajax to fetch some new text from the database each time. Both of these solutions would give 2 different types of strain upon your resources.

I'll give you the non-ajax solution, but if you want to hear the ajax one, tell me, and I'll add it here as well. If you want a piece of your website to change upon a click, you can to use javascript to accomplish this. There is also a CSS-only solution based on the current state (selected or not selected) of the radio buttons, but this javascript was easier to write for me.  ... so here you go. Solution without ajax, with javascript.

```
<?php

$radio_button_div_text = ""; //makes a variable to store all the text to be displayed in section 1
$textarea_div_text = ""; //makes a variable to store all the text to be displayed in section 1
$list_of_all_ids_for_js_function = ""; //makes a variable to store something that will later be part of the javascript function

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM clanok ORDER BY nadpis");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { //while there are rows to get...
    //put the different buttons and textareas into two separate variables
    $radio_button_div_text += 'input type="radio" name="nadpis" value="'.$row['nadpis'].'" onclick="show_only_one_textarea('.$row['nadpis'].')">';
    $radio_button_div_text += $row['nadpis'];
    $radio_button_div_text += '<br>';
    $textarea_div_text += '<textarea id='.$row['nadpis'].' name="text" cols="30" rows="5" style="display:none;">';
    $textarea_div_text += $row['text'];
    $textarea_div_text += '</textarea>';
    $list_of_all_ids_for_js_function += 'document.getElementById(\''.$row['nadpis'].'\').style.display="none";'    }

//now, after you got all the info sorted, show the two areas!    
echo $radio_button_div_text;
echo '<br><br>';
echo $textarea_div_text;

?>

<!--now, what you need, is some javascript to make some textareas visible when you click on the corresponding radio button -->
<script>
function show_only_one_textarea(area_id) {
    <?php echo $list_of_all_ids_for_js_function; ?>
    document.getElementById(area_id).style.display="block";    }
</script>

<!--now, everything will display properly and the javascript will work. here is your submit button -->
<br>                
<input type="submit"  value="Odoslať článok">
```

I'm sorry, I didn't test this code out on my own website ... it probably has a nice handful of errors with the ' " quotes. But if you read through it carefully, you will understand the idea of what is trying to be done there. Do you know anything much about javascript? Feel free to ask me more, if you need clarification!

Good luck.